# How can I add an SVG image in Laravel Dompdf?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-dompdf, barryvdh

I'm encountering an issue with adding an SVG image to Laravel Dompdf. The image appears in black and white instead of its original colors. How can I resolve this?

[Image file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVIiQ.png)

I added this code in the Blade file.

`<img class="logo" src="{{ public_path('storage/' . $settings['horizontal_logo']) }}" alt="">`

I would like to add a colour SVG image into a Laravel project in Dompdf.

Answer (score 0):

This used to be a bug in SvgLib, but it seems to have been resolved by version 0.5.3. Have you tried updating your dependencies?

Source: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/3245

Or, if at all possible, consider using a PNG or JPEG format since they are usually easier to control in PDF, where the sizes generally don't vary too much.